# Save nearest establishment to google user account in Swift2

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps-api-3, swift2, google-places-api

The purpose for this portion of the app is for the user (signed in with Google sign in) to locate the nearest place to them and save it automatically to the user's google account.

The below method works fine, grabbing the most likely place the user is located at (first object in the array of placeLikelihoods). Now what I need to do is save it to the user's google account (the one they signed in with).

Any lead or ideas on how to do this or if it's even possible? Thank you for the help like always.

```
func getInfoViaPlacesClient() {

let placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.sharedClient()

placesClient.currentPlaceWithCallback { (likelihoodlist, error) -> Void in

    if error != nil {
        print("Current Place error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }

    let nearestPlace : GMSPlaceLikelihood = likelihoodlist!.likelihoods.first as! GMSPlaceLikelihood
        print(nearestPlace.likelihood)
        self.nearestPlace = nearestPlace.place

        self.saveNearestPlace()

  }   
}
```

Save method... I think I'm on the right track but I keep getting this error in the placesClient.addPlace block...

> Add Place error: The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (com.google.places.server.ErrorDomain error -1.)

```
func saveNearestPlace() {

//to app(core data)
let placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.sharedClient()

let name = self.nearestPlace!.name
let address = self.nearestPlace!.formattedAddress

LocationController.sharedInstance.addLocationWithName(name!, address: address!)

//to google 

let addedPlace = GMSUserAddedPlace()
addedPlace.name = self.nearestPlace?.name
addedPlace.coordinate = (self.nearestPlace?.coordinate)!
addedPlace.types = self.nearestPlace?.types
addedPlace.address = self.nearestPlace?.formattedAddress

placesClient.addPlace(addedPlace, callback: { (place: GMSPlace?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    if let error = error {
        print("Add Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }

    if let place = place {

        self.nearestPlace = place

        print("Added place with placeID \(place.placeID)")
        print("Added Place name \(place.name)")
        print("Added Place address \(place.formattedAddress)")
    }
})

}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.  The `addPlace` method of `GMSPlacesClient` has nothing to do with saving a place to a user account.  What user-visible effect do you want `saveNearestPlace` to have?

Comment: Yea, I figured that out but the google docs are a little lacking. It's not going to have any effect on the interface but when they click a button I want the nearest GMSPlace (gotten in the getInfoViaPlacesClient method) to be saved to their google account (they're signed in via google). Is this at all possible? Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "save to their google account".  What does that look like to the user?  Is it like starring a place?  Anyway, I don't believe anything like that is possible.  The Google Places API does not interact with Google user accounts.

Comment: They are signed in with google in the app, that seems very odd to me that they can't interact with their google users account since I thought that would be the point of the google SDK. What is the add place method for anyway if it's not for adding a place as its name would lead you to believe?

Comment: [addPlace](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_places_client#a5951340c514f5ac2cb6ba0973ea778f5) is used to add a place that is currently not in the Google's database and/or collection of places. As @spiv said it cannot be used to save a place in a Google's account. Take a look at [Signed-in Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/signedin) documentation, this may be a good place to start to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you, that's a start but do you know if similar documentation is available for iOS/mobile?

Comment: FWIW, the point of the Google Places API is to let you make use of Google's detailed database of about 100 million places globally in your app / website / toaster.  That said, please file a feature request at http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?q=label:ApiType-PlacesAPI for your use case.  We'd like to hear more.