# Save a GMSPlace to user's current Google account using place ID

Tags: ios, swift2, google-places-api

In an app where a user is signed in via google, I want them to be able to click a button and save the place nearest them to their google account. I have the code to grab the nearest place (GMSPlace object) working fine but I'm not sure if the saving to the account part is possible, and if so how to go about it. One would think that the GMUserAddedPlace class is how to go about it but I thin that's for places that don't exist in the database.

Here is my code to get the nearest GMSPlace, it works fine then saves them to core data just for testing purposes. I couldn't find this on the documentation but is there any way using GIDGoogleUser to save it to their account using the place ID?

```
func getInfoViaPlacesClient() {

    let placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.sharedClient()

    placesClient.currentPlaceWithCallback { (likelihoodlist, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print("Current Place error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        let nearestPlace : GMSPlaceLikelihood = likelihoodlist!.likelihoods.first as! GMSPlaceLikelihood
            print(nearestPlace.likelihood)
            self.nearestPlace = nearestPlace.place

            print(self.nearestPlace?.placeID)

            self.saveNearestPlace()
    }


}
```

Where I want to save it (Core data works but not sure about the other)

```
func saveNearestPlace() {

    //to app(core data)

    let placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.sharedClient()

    let name = self.nearestPlace!.name
    let address = self.nearestPlace!.formattedAddress

    LocationController.sharedInstance.addLocationWithName(name!, address: address!)

    //to google 

    //Save place to account here ideally

}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save nearest establishment to google user account in Swift2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34969241/save-nearest-establishment-to-google-user-account-in-swift2)

Comment: That was my question too but a bit outdated and there was no answer. That question had more to do with GMSUserAddedPlace whereas this one inquires more about saving to GIDGoogleUser or GIDProfileData.

Comment: Like that question (and its comments), you still haven't stated what "saving" means here.  Where would the user see saved places?  And like I stated in the comments there you should file a feature request at https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?q=label:ApiType-PlacesAPI.

Comment: I did file a feature request but I think it already is possible. Google accounts have saved places, and from the app I want to save a GMSPlace to those saved places. In the other question, I was still under the impression that one would use GMSUserAddedPlace but now I know that's not what that's for. I think there might be a way to do it via GIDGoogleUser or GIDProfileData but I'm not sure. For further reference google 'google saved places' and look at the images. That's what I'm trying to save a GMSPlace to, from the app.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this isn't possible.

There's no iOS API for saving a place to a user's Google account like that.  The closest API that exists for what you want is for websites: [Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#place_mode)'s "Attributed Save" feature, but that's unlikely to help your iOS app.